# A function that calculates the average of a list and returns the elements that are greater than the mathematical average of the entire list

Tags: python, loops, parameters, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make a function that would calculate the average of a given list then returns all the elements within that list which are greater than the mathematical average of that list. Example:
 if the given list is [1,2,3,4,5,6], the average would be 3.5. So the function should print out the numbers (4,5,6).

I've gotten as far as adding all the numbers up within the list but no matter what I do, I can't figure out how to get the average or get it to print out the numbers that are greater than the mathematical average.

This is what i have so far to add all the elements of any given list:

```
def accum2(seq):


  total = 0

  for x in seq:
    total += x



  return total


print (accum2([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

The expected result of print (accum2([1,2,3,4,5,6])) should be (4,5,6) but so far I just get an answer where it just adds up all the number in the given list.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: The only thing `accum2()` does is add up the total and return it.  Why would you expect it to also print the larger items, when it clearly has no code to do that work?

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear with what I meant to say. I know that the code is only able to add up the total, I need help getting started with the rest of the code.

Comment: Break the problem down into steps.  The first step is to calculate the average of the sequence.  You already have the total sum of the sequence, so you're halfway there -- you also need the number of items in the sequence.  Do you know how to get that?

Comment: I know that the count() method can count how many elements are in the list, but I'm not sure how to plug it into the existing code to divide it with the total.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the average value of a list of numeric values is to use the methods:

```
average = sum(seq) / len(seq)
```

From there just use a conditional statement (you might have to sort the list first, if it is unsorted). From there you should be able to build a new list using the built in list methods.

Answer (score 0):

heres some simple code which should work. 
I have added comments.

```
    originallist = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #This is your original list
    outputlist = [] #This is the list which you can add correct values to

    x = sum(originallist) / len(originallist) #This effectively finds you the average

    for item in originallist: #Checks which items are greater than average
        if item > x:
            outputlist.append(item) #If greater, add to the final list


    print(outputlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many correct ways to do this, one of which is shown below (Python 3).

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
res = list(filter(lambda x: x > avg, lst))
print(res)
```

will produce
    [4,5,6].

I prefer this approach because it's less verbose than loops and also can be more easily translated to a framework like Pandas or an eventual parallel implementation if such a need arises in the future (e.g., using Spark).

Answer (score 0):

This is the extended version of your work:

```
def accum2(seq):
 total = 0

 for x in seq:
  total += x

 L=[]

 for x in seq:
   if x>total/len(seq):
      L.append(x)

 return L


print (accum2([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

But you could simply the previous one in this code:

```
    def accum2(seq):

      return [x for x in seq if x>(sum(y for y in seq)/len(seq))]

    print (accum2([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```